# Why does Laravel-mix "version" work locally for JS and SASS but on remote server only works for JS?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm using `"laravel-mix": "^0.10.0"` since later versions (such as [`"laravel-mix": "^2.0"`](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/2.0/versioning)) have even more problems (which I may post separate questions about).

On my local machine, the [`mix.version();`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix#versioning-and-cache-busting) feature works fine for both JS and SASS (whether I run `npm run production` or `npm run watch`).

The `mix-manifest.json` file gets updated with paths such as `"/css/app.eebc014f141ca31528c7.css"` and `"/js/common.d781da695b3fb8b3765c.js"`.

And the versioned JS and CSS files exist in the appropriate public folders.

But when I run the same `npm run production` command on the production server, only the JS files get versioned and appear in `/mix-manifest.json`.

The SCSS files get compiled into CSS without versioning.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This seems not to be a problem anymore after upgrading to 2.0

Although I don't know the answer to the question exactly, I was able to upgrade from `"laravel-mix": "^0.10.0"` to `"laravel-mix": "^2.0"` and (separately, outside the scope of this question) will deal with the fact that the Uglify options (such as `drop_console` / `clearConsole`) seem to be botched.

The versioning seems to work for JS and SASS/SCSS, though.

And I noticed that `mix-manifest.json` uses a new approach of query string (e.g. `"/css/app.css?id=89fc79b46cdbfdc944d4"`) instead of changing the filename.